# LogBack AsyncAppender loses classpath in the new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, logback

I'm using the `LogBack AsyncAppender` with a reference to my own log appender.
When the new thread is created and my appender start it seems to loose the `classpath`.

Several `ClassDefNotFoundError` occurs. If I run the my appender directly without the AsyncAppender it works just fine.

One of the `ClassDefNotFoundError` points on `StringBuffer`, but are used in one of the other classes my appender use. However, if I define and instantiate a StringBuffer object in my appender class, the error goes away.

I can make the appender work properly if instantiate all objects that points to a `ClassDefNotFoundError`

Maybe I don't understand how threads works, but what can I miss.